# How to change brush size when it’s already saved in layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

My problem is that this brush has been applied in a layer and I can't change it.

I’ve made a drawing using some path to brush .. after doing this, I’ve realized that the brush size was too thin. Any suggestions for increasing the brush size of this drawing?

English is not my first language - please excuse any language issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Filter > Other > Minimum` and adjust to your liking...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your description of process is accurate, and you have stroked paths versus painting with a brush, you can set new strokes with new widths without any trouble; the brushed strokes live in the pixel layers, but the paths are independent, so you can re-stroke them with new brushes, at new widths at any time. Make a new layer, re-select your paths, re-stroke to your preference - there you go!

This also means you can create complex effects with multiple widths and colours of stroke all from the same paths easily - or as I did below, by also shifting the pixel layer of the resulting brushwork after the fact.

[image]

[image]

Hope this help you!